# How to read an asset to inputFileStream?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My goal is to put an image in the assets folder that will later be upload to Firebase Storage. Since the image file will be packaged with the app I need to used Firebase's putStream method to upload the file. However, I am unable to read the image file into stream.

What I've tried:

```
public static InputStream readAssetsFileToStream(String fileName, Context context) {
    AssetManager assManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = assManager.open(fileName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
    }
    InputStream isOutput = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    return isOutput;
}
```

and then where the file need to be uploaded:

```
public  void uploadFile() throws IOException {

        Log.i("Firebase", "Upload started!");

       InputStream is = readAssetsFileToStream("abc", getApplicationContext());



        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; //declare the size of the byte array with size of the file
        is.read(buffer); //read file
        is.close(); //close file

        String streamData = new String(buffer);
     //   Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/raw/book.pdf"));sourc

      //  StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child("/quadcopter.pdf");


        mStorageRef.putStream(is)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Log.i("Firebase", downloadUrl.toString());
                        Log.i("Firebase", "Upload Successful!");
                    }


                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.i("Firebase", "Upload failed");
                        Log.i("Firebase", exception.getMessage());
                        // ...
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                Log.i("Firebase", "Upload Complete!");

            }
        }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Log.i("Firebase", String.valueOf(taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()));
            }
        });
    }
```

When uploading the file I get an error at :

```
    int size = is.available();
```

that says,

```
java.io.IOException: BufferedInputStream is closed
```

My Project Structure:

[image]

I need to upload the 'abc.jpg' file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your finally block of `readAssetsFileToStream` you close the stream:

```
finally {
        try {
            if (is != null)
                is.close();
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.getMessage();
        }
```

you always return a closed stream. The availability check correctly returns that the stream is closed. Btw: You can only process a stream once.

Since AssetsManager.open() is autocloseable you could write:

```
try(InputStream is = assManager.open(fileName)) {}
```

And remove the finally block. This will autoclose your stream after usage.

But I would recommend you a refactoring. Returning a stream always lets you struggle with the problem how you close it. Depending on your needs you could return it as a file or a byte[]. Both have advantages and own problems.

Comment: In case you have textfiles please remember to set the encoding to something like UTF-8 when reading/writing the file again.